# How can I register a service worker in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, service-worker

I'm trying register a service worker in Ruby On Rails to implement a push notification GCM. But nothing happens. Please, see my code below:

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('/assets/service-worker.js')
    .then(initialiseState);
  } else {
    window.Demo.debug.log('Service workers aren\'t supported in this browser.');
```

This part works fine. But, when I call `navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(function(serviceWorkerRegistration)`, nothing happens.

I was searching on search engine and there are few things to help me.

Can anybody help me ?

Comment: Are you sure `serviceWorker.ready` is part of the ServiceWorker API? I can't find any reference to it in the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API).

Comment: @nicohvi i'm following the tutorial by google. See in this link [Push Notifications on the Open Web](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/push-notificatons-on-the-open-web)

Answer (score 3):

Check out the [serviceworker-rails](https://github.com/rossta/serviceworker-rails) gem.

As Jeff mentioned, the path on which the service worker must be "in scope". This gem allows you to proxy service worker requests at the root (or any other path) to a resource in the Rails asset pipeline.

For example, if your serviceworker script entry point is in `app/assets/javascripts/nested/directory/serviceworker.js` in your Rails project, you can configure your application to render the script from `/serviceworker.js` with some simple configuration setup:

```
# config/application.rb
config.serviceworker.routes.draw do
  match "/serviceworker.js" => "nested/directory/serviceworker.js"
end
```

Answer (score 2):

The service worker script, `service-worker.js` in your case, needs to be served from either the same-directory URL path as the page that's registering it, or a sub-path.

You're using the path `/assets/service-worker.js`, so unless the registering page is also served from `/assets/`, it's going to fail. If you put a `.catch(function(error) { console.warn(error); })` at the end of your `register()` (which returns a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), you would see the error reported there.

The easiest thing to do is make sure that `service-worker.js` is served out of the same directory as the web page, and then call `register('service-worker.js')`, which uses a same-directory relative path.

Comment: Jeff, nothing happens to the changes. My JS files are in same folder. You suggest me how it would structure my rails project?

Comment: What's the URL that you use to access the page that's currently calling `register('/assets/service-worker.js')`?

Comment: Jeff, `localhost:3000/users/edit` . This view there is a code JS that register the service worker.

Comment: Right, so that's my point. You'd need to serve the `service-worker.js` code from within the same URL path in order to register from that page, so it would need to be served from `/users/edit/service-worker.js`. And then you can just call `register('service-worker.js')`

Comment: Jeff, I put at public folder and works fine. Thanks by support.